# Necessary versus sufficient conditions for deadlocks to occur

Tags: multithreading

If no thread in a multi-threaded application ever obtains more than one lock of any kind at any given time, and such locks are always released at some point, are deadlocks possible?

I imagine the answer is "no" - if another thread wants a lock that is not available, it will not be holding any lock preventing any other thread running, and will just block until the lock it wants becomes available - true?

If that is the case, at what point do deadlocks become possible? If, for example, all threads but one never obtain more than one lock at a time, can that create a deadlock? Personally I can't see how.

The classic deadlock case is where one thread has lock A, but requires lock B, while another thread has lock B and requires lock A. Clearly this is sufficient for a deadlock, but is this the minimum necessary?

Comment: What do you mean by "of any kind?"  Is there more than one type of lock that you're referring to?

Comment: Potentially yes - a mutex, a semaphore, etc - any basis for a thread to block on a synchronisation element that controls access to a shared resource.

Answer (score 1):

> An extract from Advanced concepts in Operating system
>
> The following 4 conditions are necessary for deadlock to occur
>
> 1.Exclusive access - single access to a resource
>
> 2.Wait while hold - waiting for another resource when you already have one or more
>
> 3.No preemption - only way to release a resource is for the process to die
>
> 4.Circular wait - there is a circular dependency on resources required
>
> A system is prone to DEADLOCK IF IT SATISFIES ALL THE ABOVE FOUR CONDITION

The case you have mentioned is a one request model where there is only one request for resource there is no wait and hold as the resource is released at one point of time. Hence there is no deadlock

However in case 2 or more resources request,there can be multiple ways which would lead to satisfying all the above  conditions.

The example you presented is a typical case of circular wait. One solution is to use hierarchy ie acquire lock A before lock B ... this will prevent circular wait .

I would suggest to get more idea read AND REQUEST MODEL, OR REQUEST MODEL, P OUT OF Q REQUEST MODEL and of course ONE REQUEST MODEL

Answer (score 0):

A deadlock can occur if one thread locks, and another thread wants to obtain a lock on the same lock object, but the first thread never releases its lock (perhaps because the first thread is waiting on a condition that must be set by the second thread, but the second thread never sets that condition because it cannot obtain a lock).

As you can see, creating deadlocks deliberately is actually quite an easy thing to do.

Comment: But... if "such locks are always released at some point" and are not conditional on data set by other threads, then....?

Comment: Then you won't deadlock.  A deadlock occurs when a lock that another thread is waiting on never gets released.  The tricky part, of course, is writing programs in a way that guarantees locks are always released.